# Creating a rule to disable some options in a form

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form:
http://leagueipsum.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/blog-post.html

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
<tr><td><div class="current_tier">
<select id="ct">
            <option value="b">Bronze</option>
            <option value="s">Prata</option>
            <option value="g">Ouro</option>
            <option value="p">Platina</option>
            <option value="d">Diamante</option>
</select>
<select id="cd">
            <option>5</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>
</select>
        </div>
</td>

<td><div class="desired_tier">
<select id="dt">
            <option value="b">Bronze</option>
            <option value="s">Prata</option>
            <option value="g">Ouro</option>
            <option value="p">Platina</option>
            <option value="d">Diamante</option>
</select>
      <select id="dd">
            <option>5</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>
</select>
        </div>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

And I want to add two more options:

```
            <option value="b">Bronze</option>
            <option value="s">Prata</option>
            <option value="g">Ouro</option>
            <option value="p">Platina</option>
            <option value="d">Diamante</option>
            <option value="m">Mestre</option>
            <option value="c">Desafiante</option>
```

But that two new options does not have the 1-5 option, how can I disable the numbers options, every time that one of them were selected?

Comment: it is not hard, google it, there is no need for SO here ;), use jquery

Comment: Why are you recommending jQuery? What does it offer that specifically helps, that isn't available in plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

**Using Javascript:**

You can do it like this:

```
function validate() {
    var selectTags = document.getElementById("current_tier");
    var selectedValue = selectTags.options[selectTags.selectedIndex].value;
    if (selectedValue == "m" && "c") {
         document.getElementById("dd").disabled=true;
    }
}
```

Check out this link for more information:

[How to check if an item is selected from an HTML drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987140/how-to-check-if-an-item-is-selected-from-an-html-drop-down-list)

**Using jQuery:**

You can also use jQuery to do it. First, make sure you have included jQuery libraries in your head tags. Just copy the following code in your head tags:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then you should give those two options an id. For example:

```
<option value="m" id="special">Mestre</option>
<option value="c" id="special">Desafiante</option>
```

Then just add the following code in your head tags:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     if ($("#special").is(":checked")) {
         $('#dd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
     }
     else {
         $('#pizza_kind').prop('disabled', false);
     }
})
```

Comment: Was the question tagged with jQuery? No. Does jQuery offer anything not available in plain JavaScript? No. So: *why the jQuery answer*?

Comment: @DavidThomas You're Right! I just added a way to do it with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

with javascript

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td><div class="current_tier">
    <select id="ct" onChange="y();">
        <option value="b">Bronze</option>
        <option value="s">Prata</option>
        <option value="g">Ouro</option>
        <option value="p">Platina</option>
        <option value="d">Diamante</option>
        <option value="m">Mestre</option>
        <option value="c">Desafiante</option>
    </select>
    <select id="cd">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </td>

    <td><div class="desired_tier">
    <select id="dt" onChange="x();">
        <option value="b">Bronze</option>
        <option value="s">Prata</option>
        <option value="g">Ouro</option>
        <option value="p">Platina</option>
        <option value="d">Diamante</option>
        <option value="m">Mestre</option>
        <option value="c">Desafiante</option>
    </select>
    <select id="dd">
        <option>5</option>
        <option>4</option>
        <option>3</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>1</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
    <script>
    var ct = document.getElementById("ct");
    var dt = document.getElementById("dt");


    function y() {
    if (ct.value == "m" || ct.value == "c" ) {
    document.getElementById('cd').style.display="none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('cd').style.display="inline-block";
    }
    }

    function x() {
    if (dt.value == "m" || dt.value == "c" ) {
    document.getElementById('dd').style.display="none";
    } else {
    document.getElementById('dd').style.display="inline-block";
    }
    }

    </script>   
    </body>

    </html>
```

So we first add a on change at our select tag so when we select one of options it will fire a function.
Inside of function we want to check if we have select those two, then if we have select them hide numbers options.