# How to check if all select boxes has selected option using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have 7 simple select boxes:

```
<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>
```

How can I check if ALL the select boxes have something selected rather than the default option?

Comment: where is option value?

Comment: Set the `value` of the `select` input.... If value attribute is not specified, `text` will be treated as `value`..

Comment: You get the Element in any number of ways, such as `document.getElemnetById('HTMLidAttribute')` then it could be as simple as testing for `Element.selected`.

Comment: then you can check that via jquery at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15987166/5813861)

Answer (score 3):

You can find selected option that are disabled, if length==0 then no default element are selected.

```
if($('option[disabled]:selected').length == 0){
   // ALL the select boxes have something selected rather than the default option
}
```

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes. i was going to log the error first then changed the text . thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Get value of select and check if its null and increment the count if its not.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
    var count = 0;

    $('select').each(function(){
      
    if($(this).val() != null){
       count ++; 
     }
     
  })
    if(count == 4) {
      console.log('all selected');
    }
  })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<select>
  <option selected disabled>choose something</option>
  <option>some text</option>
  <option>some more text</option>
  <option>and more and more</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Check</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't work - you need to move the `var count = 0;` *inside* the event handler.

Comment: Thanks @nnnnnn . It was a silly mistake on my side. I edited the code

Comment: This suggestions work perfectly for my situation, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
            var count = 0;
            $("select").each(function() {
                if(this.value === ''){
                    count++
                }
            });
            if (count === 0) {
                // all select boxes has selected option 
            }
```