# How to iterated through selected <option>s in <select multiple>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are many question already existing similar to this topic however I can't find any that address this specific problem.

If I have a `<select>` element where multiple selections are allowed, how can I iterate ONLY through ones that the user has SELECTED.

jQuery and/or Vanilla accepted.

```css
select{
    overflow:auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<select id="the_select" size="5" multiple>
  <option>Bob</option>
  <option>John</option>
  <option>Sam</option>
  <option>Jason</option>
  <option>Sarah</option>
</select>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mtg73Lep/

---

**Similar Posts that don't help:**

[Iterate through <select> options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950152/iterate-through-select-options) - For all options, not just selected ones

[How to check if an item is selected from an HTML drop down list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15987140/how-to-check-if-an-item-is-selected-from-an-html-drop-down-list) - Doesn't work for `multiple` selections

Comment: @mplungjan My bad.  Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/k39nj8vw/ `$("#the_select").on("change",function() {
  console.log(
   $("option:selected",this).map(function() { return $(this).val() } ).get()
  )
});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
  $('option:selected').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
  });
});
```

```css
select{
    overflow:auto;
    width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="the_select" size="5" multiple>
  <option>Bob</option>
  <option>John</option>
  <option>Sam</option>
  <option>Jason</option>
  <option>Sarah</option>
</select>
```

---

Another excellent (better? *definitely cooler!*) suggestion, by resident j-Maven [mplungjan](https://plungjan.name/):

```
$("#the_select").on("change",function() { 
    console.log( $("option:selected",this).map(function() { return $(this).val() } ).get() ) 
});
```

Comment: `$("#the_select").on("change",function() {
  console.log(
   $("option:selected",this).map(function() { return $(this).val() } ).get()
  )
});`

Comment: Excellent code suggestion - many thanks. Love the Ask-Me-A-Question service on your personal site - best regards for 2019!

Comment: Yw- it’s a continuation from irt.org - have answered a million+ questions since ‘97

Comment: And thanks for the kind words